# How can I deploy with Capistrano from an SVN repo on the deployment target machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I've been using Capistrano to deploy for a while, but always with the SVN repository on a different machine from the production host I'm deploying to.

Now I have a situation where the repository and the production machine are the same. Here is my `deploy.rb` file...

```
set :application, 'my_app'
set :repository, "file:///home/ethan/svn/my_app/trunk"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/#{application}"
set :use_sudo, false

role :app, 'ethan@my_production_host.com'

namespace :deploy do
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    # Do nothing.
  end

  desc "Restart Application"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end
```

Here's what Capistrano returns when I try to deploy (I'm running this command on my development machine)...

```
$ cap deploy
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "svn info file:///home/ethan/svn/my_app/trunk  -rHEAD"
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/ethan/svn/my_app/trunk'
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/my_app/releases/20110919111200; true"
    servers: ["my_production_host.com"]
    [ethan@my_production_host.com] executing command
    command finished
Command svn info file:///home/ethan/svn/my_app/trunk  -rHEAD returned status code 256
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the `local_repository` option as is documented here: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Significant-Configuration-Variables.